# Prove that frontier of a subset is a closed set

Tags: general-topology

I need some help with a prove.

Let $A \subsetneq R^n$. $fr A$ is a closed set. Prove that is true.

Proof: If $fr A$ is closed than  $ R^n \setminus fr A$ is an open set.

Now I should prove that $ R^n \setminus fr A$, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

It's that a good start or I should prove it in another way?

Comment: What is your definition of the frontier? (I believe it is usually called "boundary")

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should use frontier or boundy.
Definitions of frontier is: $x \in R^n$ .For every radius $r > 0$ the open ball $B^r (x)$ has no empty interesection with set $A$ and its complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer it is preassumed that frontier and boundary are the same. The information in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) tells us that ambiguity is not excluded.

---

If $x\notin\text{fr}(A)$ then by definition: $$B(x,r)\subseteq A\vee B(x,r)\subseteq A^c$$ for some $r>0$.

(Note that $B(x,r)\subseteq A\iff B(x,r)\cap A^c=\varnothing$ and $B(x,r)\subseteq A^c\iff B(x,r)\cap A=\varnothing$)

For every $y\in B(x,r)$ there is some $r_y>0$ such that $B(y,r_y)\subseteq B(x,r)$, since $B(x,r)$ is open.

Consequently we have: $$B(y,r_y)\subseteq A\vee B(y,r_y)\subseteq A^c$$ for every $y\in B(x,r)$ telling us that actually $B(x,r)$ is a subset of the complement of $\text{fr}(A)$.

This can be done for every $x\notin\text{fr}(A)$, so proved is now that the complement of $\text{fr}(A)$ is an open set, or equivalently that $\text{fr}(A)$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\text{fr}(A) = \text{cl}(A) \setminus \mathring{A} = \text{cl}(A) \cap (\mathring{A})^c$. Therefore $\text{fr}(A)$ is the intersection of
two closed sets, yielding that it is closed itself.

---

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \text{fr}(A)$. By your very definition of frontier, we know there exists $r > 0$ such that either $B(x_0, r) \cap A = \emptyset$ or $B(x_0, r) \cap A^c = \emptyset$. Suppose for instance $B(x_0, r) \cap A = \emptyset$ . Then for $y \in B(x_0, r)$, $B(y, \frac{d(x_0,y)}{2}) \cap A = \emptyset$, such that we have $y \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \text{fr}(A)$. Therefore $B(x_0, r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \text{fr}(A)$, yielding that it is open!

Comment: I don't think i can use $cl A$ because we didn't prove it yet. That's the next exercise: To prove that $cl A$ is a closed set.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu Now take a look ;)

Comment: I don't understad this part $B(x_0, r) \cap A = \emptyset$ or $B(x_0, r) \cap A^c = \emptyset$. By my frontier definition both intersections must have at least one element or am I missing something?

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu you are missing that in this answer $x_0$ is **not** an element of $\text{fr}(A)$ (hence at least one of the mentioned intersections is empty, as said).